# What PHP frameworks can create/access email accounts?

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I'd like to create email accounts (email@myserver.com) dynamically as well as access the email to check and send mail. I currently use Codeigniter as my framework, but I couldn't find any working libraries to do this.

I've looked online and it appears Zend Framework can check your emails, I don't know if it can create email accounts though. From my research it appears that I can only create accounts through the cpanel or plesk api's. Are there any frameworks then with cpanel api libraries I can get?

Comment: You can use the [xmlapi-php](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php) class to interface with cpanel. The class is framework-agnostic so it doesn't matter what framework you're using. btw: In cPanel there's already a webmail-thing included: why bother reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I appreciate it. I'd prefer something that is customized for a single framework if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the comments the correct answer. Plesk provides a XML-API

[Plesk PHP API How to use](http://www.ehow.com/how_10054410_send-plesk-api-php-command.html)
[Creating an A-Record with Plesk API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175816/creating-an-a-record-with-plesk-api)
[Autoinstallation Wordpress by Plesk API in subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688229/autoinstallation-wordpress-by-plesk-api-in-subdomain)

here are some sites how to use it and some hits. Here on Stackoverflow are some posts that can help you with your problem.